# Can't get Identity Server 4 API to authorize its own endpoints, sends login page instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, identityserver4

## What works so far

I have two ASP.NET Core APIs:

1. A business API, manages business entities (think Products, Menus, etc)
2. An IS4 API, manages Users and Authentication and is used to authorize users for access to the first

How I did this: my controllers on the second API are authorized using `Authorize(Roles = "Admin")` so only admins can access it. example :

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MenuController {
   ...
}
```

Basically, my front end uses the IS4 API to log in, which returns a JWT which is in turn used to authenticate itself to the business API. In my `Startup.cs` for the business API I have this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()));
    
    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });
    
    services.AddApplication();
    services.AddInfrastructure(Configuration);
    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

## My problem

The above works fine. I'm trying to do the same thing on some endpoints of my IS4 API to reserve some actions to admin users (deleting users, registering users). here's a basic endpoint I created in a controller for this purpose :

```cs
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/[controller]/debug")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DebugEndpoint()
{
    return Ok("debug ok");
}
```

I also registered the API as its own authority in `Startup.cs`, the same way I did the first API:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()));
    
    services.AddHealthChecks();

    services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
            options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
            options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30; // interval in seconds
        })
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
        .AddTestUsers(Config.TestUsers)
        .AddAspNetIdentity<AppUser>();

    services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();
    
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
        {
            var is4Policy =  options.GetPolicy(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.PolicyName);
            policy.Combine(is4Policy);
            policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin");
        });
    });
    

    services.AddTransient<IProfileService, IdentityClaimsProfileService>();

    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });


    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);

}

public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
    {
        builder.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            if (error != null)
            {
                context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        });
    });

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions { MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None });
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

## Expected result

I should only be able to access the debug endpoint and obtain "debug ok" if I'm logged in, or with a certain role when I add `(Roles = "Admin")` in the annotation.

## Actual result

Unless I delete the `[Authorize]` annotation, it always just gives me a second call to the login page. I'm passing the access token in authorization, the same way I do with the other API, but while it authorizes me with the other API, with this one it doesn't, acting as though I didn't even pass an access token, and I can't understand why.

Comment: Are you running from VS?  VS doesn't automatically start with ADMIN.  You need to right click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: This isn't a real Windows admin status, it's just a claim passed in the JWT.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to my endpoints.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes="Bearer")]
```